MySQL- To automatically insert sum of three columns in third column
I have a table named 'question' which has four columns namely- 'total_correct', total_wrong', 'total_notattempted', 'total'. I want that when data in first three columns i.e. 'total_correct', total_wrong', 'total_notattempted' are inserted then their sum should be automatically inserted in fourth column i.e. 'total'.
Since i want the 'total' column to be automatically updated with the sum of first three columns, i used SQL Trigger. This trigger gets activated whenever data is inserted in these three columns i.e. 'total_correct', total_wrong', 'total_notattempted'. Please also note that all these three columns can have 'NULL' value so i converted them to 0 before adding. When data is inserted in three columns then this trigger automatically updates the 'total' column. So i used the following SQL query-
DELIMITER //

CREATE TRIGGER calculate_total
AFTER INSERT ON question
FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
    DECLARE correct INT DEFAULT 0;
    DECLARE wrong INT DEFAULT 0;
    DECLARE not_attempted INT DEFAULT 0;

    IF NEW.total_correct IS NOT NULL THEN
        SET correct = NEW.total_correct;
    END IF;

    IF NEW.total_wrong IS NOT NULL THEN
        SET wrong = NEW.total_wrong;
    END IF;

    IF NEW.total_notattempted IS NOT NULL THEN
        SET not_attempted = NEW.total_notattempted;
    END IF;

    SET NEW.total = correct + wrong + not_attempted;
END //

DELIMITER ;

When i tried to execute the above code, i got following error- #1362 - Updating of NEW row is not allowed in after trigger.
When i used, BEFORE INSERT ON then the code was executed without any error but that's not my need. The 'total' column should display the sum after the values are inserted and not before. Because when i used before trigger, it inserted '0' in 'total' column because it was calculating sum before the values are inserted. How can i make sure that my 'total' column gets automatically updated after values are inserted in first three columns? I don't want to do this manually. It should automatically calculate and insert the total in 'total' column.

Use generated column or a view or just a select statement
